# How this lock block works?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I saw a header file as below:

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define lock(x) if(Lock _lock_=x){}else

class Mutex{
    public:
        Mutex(){
            pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, 0);
        };

        ~Mutex(){
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
        };

        friend class Lock;

    private:
        pthread_mutex_t mutex_;

        void Lock(){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
        };

        void Unlock(){
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
        };
};

class Lock{
    public:
        Lock(Mutex& mutex):mutex_(mutex){mutex_.Lock();};
        ~Lock(){mutex_.Unlock();};

        operator bool() const {
            return false;
        }

    private:
        Mutex& mutex_;
};
```

It defines a `lock(x)` macro. And below is how this macro is being used:

```
...
Mutex mtx;
lock(mtx) {
  // critical section
}
...
```

So, how this lock macro works? And why?

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a little on-paper macro expansion here:

Your macro =

```
#define lock(x) if(Lock _lock_=x){}else
```

And the use of it:

```
Mutex mtx;
lock(mtx) {
  // critical section
}
```

Becomes, after macro substitutions:

```
Mutex mtx;
if(Lock _lock_=mtx)
{
  // BLOCK 1
}
else
{
  // BLOCK 2
  // critical section
}
```

So, `_lock_` is being copy-assigned from `mtx`, which attempts to lock the mutex by calling `pthread_mutex_lock`, which [returns `0` if succesful](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) and blocks if the mutex is already blocked.

The `if` block is calling `Lock::operator bool()`, which always returns `false`:

operator bool() const {
        return false;
    }

Since this always returns `false`, the block I markeed `BLOCK 1` is never taken, and your critical section code (`BLOCK 2`) is called instead.

Comment: Why can it use copy-assign from Mutex type to a Lock type?

Comment: @injoy:  Because `Lock` has a constructor which takes a `Mutex&`.

Comment: BTW, do you know why the program use Mutex& mutex_; in the Lock class? I mean the & symbol.

Comment: @injoy: `Mutex&` means reference-to-`Mutex`.

Comment: So the copy-assignment means reference, not creating a new copy, right?

Answer (score 2):

So, the preprocessor will expand the macro in-place (essentially inserting it into the code). So your example becomes:

```
...
Mutex mtx;
if(Lock _lock_=mtx){}else {
  // critical section
}
...
```

Or, with some better formatting,

```
...
Mutex mtx;
if(Lock _lock_=mtx)
{
}
else
{
  // critical section
}
...
```

It locks the Mutex via the constructor of the `Lock` class, and the expression in the `if()` statement always evaluates to `false` because of the implementation of `Lock`'s `operator bool() const`, so the code in the `else { }` portion is executed.

I think I'll also mention that I would argue that this is a ... more convoluted than necessary way to do this. It would be "just as easy" (and probably more easily understandable) to just declare a new `Lock` at the beginning of your scope, and do away with the macro entirely. This is how, for example, [Qt's QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmutexlocker.html) is used.